# How to measure object size from the disparity map using CNN?

Tags: convolutional-neural-networks, computer-vision, object-detection, image-processing

I am a student learning about image processing using CNN. I want to learn how to measure the object size from the [disparity map](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7337323/3924118) obtained from left and right stereo images.